# Call non-static function inside laravel blade view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a set of classes that are php files that contains functions which are not static (a set of files for image resizing that the client is determined on using them, they don't belong to any namespace, just old ordinary php files).

I need to call a method called imageResize from one of these files, what's the best approach for achieving this from a laravel 5.2 application?

Comment: functions or class methods? Regardless, why would you be resizing images in a view file?

Comment: because the requirements is to resize images on the fly

Comment: Sure, but in that case use a helper class that you pass to the view, or define a route that calls a image controller. And what about the 1st part of my question - are these class methods, or functions?

Comment: They are methods, they take arguments and return an image, I tried using a helper file and registering it with a service provider, but in this case the methods need to be static which isn't the case, as the methods and files are dependent on each other

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

1. Say your filename is **my_all_functions.php**. Copy this file to 'app/Http' directory.
2. Edit **composer.json** file.
3. Add these to your composer.json file

   ```
   "autoload": {
      "files": [
               "app/Http/my_all_functions.php"
             ]
   }
   ```
4. Now you can access your custom functions from everywhere.

Comment: I am on a shared hosting, can't run `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 0):

For a quick dirty job, use this:

```
{!! with(new MyClass())->someFunc($params) !!}
```

But consider using a [service provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/providers), and register you class with [container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/container) if possible. That's the Laravel way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can access the non-static function inside the blade file. but you need to create the object of the model class. so that you can access it. follow the codes below:-

```
@php
   $obj_tc = new App\admin();
   $getTc = $obj_tc->getTcName($tcname);
   echo $getTc->tc_name;
@endphp
```